# Applying jQuery .click() to Ajax-generated HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I'm using jQuery to manage the "Edit" button on comments for an app I'm coding. In my `document.ready`, I have:

```
$('.edit-button').click(function(){
// Code to trigger the editing interface for parent comment
});
```

I'm also using jQuery to display newly-posted comments without refreshing the page. Within the relevant `$.ajax()` function, I write the new comment to the DOM using a `$.before(data)`. Problem is, the `.edit-button`s within `data` don't have the aforementioned `$.click()` applied to them, because that happens in `document.ready`. So I click on them, and nothing happens.

I've tried the (extremely ugly) solution of having the Ajax function re-include the .js file in which I call `document.ready`. This works, except it re-applies the `.click()` to every single `.edit-button`, so they open the editing interface twice (or even three times).

So, how can I re-apply the `$.click()`s from `document.ready`? Preferably without having to copypasta my `document.ready` function into another javascript file, in case I modify it later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depend on your version of jQuery, there are these solution:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

obviously the last one `.on()` is the best choise. [More Information](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

but about `.bind()`:

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those **elements must exist at the point the call** to `.bind()` occurs. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

For your problem answer is something like these:

```
$('.edit-button').on("click",function(){  })
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-button", function(){  });
```

**Note**:
Use of the `.live()` method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. [More Information](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

**Update**
`.live()` removed after jQuery 1.9 upgrade

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('body').on("click", ".edit-button", function(){

})
```

you might be able to change the body selector with something more targeted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using AJAX, you need to use the "live()" API.

```
$('.edit-button').live("click", function(){
// Code to trigger the editing interface for parent comment
});
```

Comment: this needs to be up voted more. As more and more use AJX to create dynamic data without reloading the DOM, this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.edit-button').bind('click', function() {
// Code to trigger the editing interface for parent comment
});
```

Or in your ajax success function after the comments have posted you can add it like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    // ...
    success: function (data) {
        //comment posted successfully
        $('.edit-button').unbind("click");
        $('.edit-button').bind("click", editButtonClickHandler);
});

function editButtonClickHandler () {
    //.. handle click
}
```