# rails 3.2 not detecting javascript changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

i am a newbie in rails 3.2. now i have a problem following:
i have 2 patials for showing highchart are _device_per_product.html.erb and device_per_platform.html.erb. and i render these by this way:

```
jQuery("#element_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'partial_page')) %>");
```

when i click a link to render my partial,it works. but next time, i render another partial,it just load javascript code but not generate highchart form these code.
In my opinion,For First time the javascript is freshly loading in my page. So it will work. Next time my javascript is not working. please help me solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like:

```
$('#element_div a').click(function() {
  //do something
});
```

This only binds to what's on the page when it fires.    If you are introducing new (or replacing) this then you need to change the listener.

```
$(document).on("click","#element_div a", function () {
  // do something
  }} );
```

A more detailed explanation along with alternatives for older versions of jquery can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10394566/2197771